# VBA to SQL Link best practice and performance

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have the following problem. Normally, when I generate a string with a SQL command in VBA, it takes not more than a few seconds to retrieve the results (several of the run queries are quite "heavy").

However, in one "light" case it takes up to several minutes, when sending it from VBA to SQL. BUT, when I run the SQL code by itself in SQL Server, the code is run under one second. So I think, there's a problem with my connection function between VBA and SQL? I've listed both codes below:

First, I have the following code to establish a connection between my VBA script and SQL-Server (input: SQL string; output: SQL-Server table result)

```
Private Function GetSQLData(ByVal SQLString As String)
    Dim sCon As String
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

    sCon = "Provider = "MSDASQL.1;"
    sCon = sCon & "driver={SQL Server};"
    sCon = sCon & "Server=PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS;"
    sCon = sCon & "Database=HELLOFORUM;"
    sCon = sCon & "uid="";"
    sCon = sCon & "pwd:="";"

    '/ I create the connection to SQL Server
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cnn
        .Open sCon
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .CommandTimeout = 0
    End With


    '/ Load results
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rst
        .CursorLocation = adUseServer
        .Open Source:=SQLString, ActiveConnection:=cnn, CursorType:=adOpenForwardOnly, _
        LockType:=adLockOptimistic, Options:=adCmdText
    End With

    If rst.State = 1 Then
        If Not rst.EOF Then
            GetSQLData = rst.GetRows()
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

I have a database, that looks like the following:

```
ID   timetag              val
ID01 1990-01-01 00:00:00  20
ID01 1990-01-01 00:01:00  23
[...]
```

The code that generates problems, is the following:

```
WITH rows AS (
    SELECT *,Row_Number() Over (ORDER BY timetag) as RN FROM [Database.dbo]
where ID = 'ID01' AND timetag between '1990-01-01 00:00:00' AND '1990-01-20 00:00:00')
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,mc.timetag,mp.timetag) as differ1, mc.timetag as timetag1 ,mp.timetag as timetag2
    FROM rows mc  JOIN rows mp On mc.rn = mp.rn - 1 where   DATEDIFF(minute,mc.timetag,mp.timetag) > 1 order by timetag1
```

The output of this query is a table, where the difference between subsequent timetags is not equal 1 (min). E.g.:

```
differ1    timetag1               timetag2
2          1990-07-04 00:00:00    1990-07:04 00:02:00
```

As I said, it runs fast in SQL-server, but very slow when I try to execute the query from VBA. Any suggestions - in particular so I follow "best/better practice" options for connecting to the SQL server from VBA?

Update: Even more weird, it's only slow from month 7 and upwards.

Comment: Use a parameterised query or, better still, a stored procedure. I'm sure SQL is doing some kind of optimisation / compilation / regularisation / other fancy term-ion that ado can't exploit

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: thanks for the read @MitchWheat

Comment: @MitchWheat Thank you for the link

Answer (score 0):

If you only plan to read the records you could try changing the LockType to adLockReadOnly.

You could also change the cursor location from client to server (AdUseServer).

Comment: Unfortunately, modifying one or both options did not improve execution time (and I'm at a later step also planning on altering the data)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?  That would tell you which line is under performing.  I suspect it'll be either when you open the recordset or when you GetRows.

Comment: It's during the opening of the recordset

Comment: Have you tried switching from MSDASQL to the SQL Native Client (SQLNCLI11)?  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx

Comment: Doesn't sounds like there are any ADO config changes that can help you here.  Instead it's time to look to SQL.  You could try running SQL Profiler against the query in SSMS and via VBA.  This should help you track the differences.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I circumvented the problem by changing my CTE to a temp table. Though this doesn't solve the overall issue, it's a solution that works temporarily...